# Calculate rotation to straighten a line

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

We're building a selfie straightener :)
Users upload a slightly off-center selfie; we fix it's rotation so its straight.

---

- The users click on the middle of their nose and the middle of
  their eyebrows on their face within the image.
- From there we get 2 points **eyebrowMiddle(x1,y1)** and **noseMiddle
  (x2,y2).**

**The Question**

> Is it possible via these 2 points to calculate how much Canvas
> rotation we need to have to rotate the image and make the face straight
> in relation to the canvas rectangle?

---

**PS:**

- **x1,y1** and **x2,y2** are in relation to the *canvas perimeter(the orange perimeter in the image)* of course,
  not the browser window or anything else.
- I'm using the line equation, for now, such as m = (x2-x1) / (y2-y1) but the
  result is always near 1 so I don't think we are following the right
  course at the moment.
- We don't care if the image looks wrong in the canvas as long as the
  face features are parallel in relation to the bottom of the canvas
  (they should be looking straight).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a vertical line passing through $(x_2,y_2)$ and a horizontal line passing through $(x_1,y_1)$. We want to find the angle $\theta$ between the slanted line and the vertical line. We can do this with a primary trig ratio:
$$
\theta = \arctan\left( \frac{x_2 - x_1}{y_2 - y_1} \right)
$$
where positive angles are considered counterclockwise and negative angles are considered clockwise.